# Error message: undefined control sequence\includegraphics

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm getting the error message:

> "undefined control sequence\includegraphics"

when a try to compile the file:

```
\documentclass{amsart}[12pt]
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics{cp1.pstex_t}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I use WinEdt and compile with PdfTexify. If I compile with XeLaTeX it runs ok.

What should I do to run it properly with PdfTexify?

Here is the entire code:

Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "FiguraTeste.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\Ronaldo\Documents

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(FiguraTeste.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty (C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty)
) (C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty)) (C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\caption\subcaption.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty))))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty (C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
) (C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty))))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty))))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty))))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\auto-pst-pdf\auto-pst-pdf.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex)))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty))" "
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.997 Copyright 2017 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2017.07.30:1851' -> FiguraTeste-autopp.ps
<C:/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro><C:/texmf/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
<C:/texmf/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
<C:/texmf/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
<C:/texmf/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
<C:/texmf/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro><C:/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1
<./cp1.ps>] 
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"

(C:\texmf\tex\latex\pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\luatex85\luatex85.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 77, version
               `2017/06/01' of package graphicx,
               but only version
               `2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)'
               is available.

(C:\texmf\tex\latex\pstricks\pstricks.sty (C:\texmf\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pstricks\pstricks.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pstricks\pst-fp.tex `pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex)))
`PSTricks' v2.73a  <2017/05/22> (tvz)
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pstricks\pstricks.con))
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\pstricks\pst-fp.tex))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\preview\preview.sty)
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def)
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\environ\environ.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\trimspaces\trimspaces.sty))))
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\type1cm\type1cm.sty)
(C:\texmf\tex\latex\eso-pic\eso-pic.sty
(C:\texmf\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty)) (FiguraTeste.aux)
(C:\texmf\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
(cp1.pstex_t <FiguraTeste-pics.pdf, id=2, page=1, 258.9675pt x 121.45375pt>
<use FiguraTeste-pics.pdf, page 1>
! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@setfile ...Gin@page \@empty \else (\Gin@page 
                                                  )\fi }
l.2 \includegraphics{cp1.ps}
                            %
?
```

Comment: The inclusion of a `.pstex_t` file leads me to believe you're actually looking for `\input{cp1.pstex_t}` as opposed to `\includegraphics{cp1.pstex_t}`.

Comment: you have not shown the full error message, `\includegraphics` is the indication of the line in the source where the error occurred the error message in the log will show which command is undefined, so if you show the error message it would be easier to helo.

Comment: Hi Christian! Thanks for your message. I changed to \input{cp1.pstex_t} as you suggested, but I got the same error message. Here it is: Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
(cp1.pstex_t <FiguraTeste-pics.pdf, id=2, page=1, 258.9675pt x 121.45375pt>
<use FiguraTeste-pics.pdf, page 1>
! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@setfile ...Gin@page \@empty \else (\Gin@page 
                                                  )\fi }
l.2 \includegraphics{cp1.ps}
                            %
?

Comment: it is hard to tell which command is undefined from your comment (you need to post it as a code section in the question as it is the position of the line break that is important, as that marks which command is undefined) but if it is `\Gin@page` if you update your tex system (graphics and graphics-def packages for miktex or texlive) then that should work again

Comment: Ok David, I will try to edit the question and post the entire code. Thanks.

Comment: @RonaldoFreire: I suggested nothing ;-) That was Werner's proposition

Comment: Oh, OK Christian, sorry. :) Thanks Werner, for the message.

Comment: The control sequence/macro that caused the error is the last one before  the linebreak in the error block. So in this case, `\Gin@page`. Have you tried updating as suggested by @DavidCarlisle?

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error when using `graphicx` with `auto-pst-pdf` and – more importantly – received the same / a similar warning, *i.e.*

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 77, version
               `2017/06/01' of package graphicx,
               but only version
               `2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)'
               is available.
```

In my case, updating `graphicx` seemed to resolve the issue – it's included in the `graphics` package.

Happily, a compendium of [updating instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) have been compiled as a community wiki.